# Seeking reservoir data set for UK?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I was looking for reservoir data to understand who owns which reservoir, could not find it over the internet.

Anybody knows where I can find it?

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: you will have to contact each Water Company in England & Wales https://discoverwater.co.uk/water-sector has a map

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be the [data.gov.uk](https://data.gov.uk/search?q=reservoirs) website, which holds metadata for UK organizations, such as the Environment Agency, and Natural Resources Wales.

For example you might find the following useful:

- [Inventory of reservoirs amounting to 90% of total UK storage](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/aa1e16e8-eded-4a60-8d1d-0df920c319b6/inventory-of-reservoirs-amounting-to-90-of-total-uk-storage)
- [Large Raised Reservoirs](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/9827bf78-8087-49f3-8d65-1e8abb401566/large-raised-reservoirs)

Comment: Hi, there thank you very much,  its seems the data isn't publicly available but will have to request through freedom of information to holding body. Very helpful,  thank you.